# Съезжает картинка при прозрачном статус баре

Tags: android, android-studio

Я пытаюсь сделать прозрачный статус бар.
Я добавил в Style следующее:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Но возникает вот такая проблема:
[image: Проблема]

Везде советуют добавить в Layout: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` (я использую CoordinatorLayout). Но при его добавлении, картинка съезжает ещё ниже

Comment: <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> Вы это добавляли?

Comment: @Valgaal Добавлял. Картинка все равно не доходит до конца экрана сверху

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать это программно:

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

или вот так с вашими настройками стилей:

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```